# Как обработать webhook telegram Node js

Tags: node.js, api, telegram-bot, telegram

Хочу сделать бота на Node js на базе node-telegram-bot-api

Как я могу обработать webhook?

Answer (score 0):

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const TOKEN = 'ВАШ_ТОКЕН';

const options = {
    webHook: {
        port: process.env.PORT
    }
};
const url = "ВАШ_URL";
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, options);
```